# sending it to Email and Google docs (form)

Tags: jquery, forms, google-docs

I am planning to create a contact form that sends its data to Google Docs and to an email... what are the possibilities and approaches? I like building froms from Google Docs, my only worry if I build my form based on google docs, I might not have the capability to reply on the email. like the regular gmail functions.

Here's my goal. I want to use Google Docs to build my database of emails and contacts, I also want it to send in my email so I can easily reply to them.

Please advice me what approach I can do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apps Script to accomplish most of this. You can set an trigger to run a function each time a form is submitted. Maybe that script could send you an email with the content of the form and send an auto-reply to the user. You can automate a lot of other actions via scripts as well. There's a [tutorial on automating a simple helpdesk workflow](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/helpdesk_tutorial.html) that might be relevant to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give these instructions a try:

[Adding a submission form](http://www.blogxpertise.com/2011/11/tip-adding-submission-form-to-your-blog.html)

Followed by:

[Making a Google Doc submission form email you the results](http://www.blogxpertise.com/2012/04/tip-making-google-doc-submission-form.html)